# How to select the most oldest data from duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query from a table like this:

| ID | product | revenue | data | device |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | A | 10 | 2022-06-17 08:02:00.693 | mobile |
| 01 | A | 10 | 2022-06-17 10:02:00.693 | desk |
| 03 | G | 10 | 2022-06-17 09:02:00.693 | mobile |
| 03 | G | 10 | 2022-06-17 10:02:00.693 | desk |

As you can see the table contains duplicates for ID, product and revenues.
I would like to select the duplicate with the most oldest date like this:

| ID | product | revenue | data | device |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | A | 10 | 2022-06-17 08:02:00.693 | mobile |
| 03 | G | 10 | 2022-06-17 09:02:00.693 | mobile |

I'm looking for an efficient query, I tried with the statement TOP, but it doesn't work

**Database: T-SQL**

Comment: Which Database are you using?

Comment: Database: T-SQL. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned the most recent date, but in the expected result you have mentioned records with old date.

You can get most recent data by using `desc` in order by. If you remove `desc`, it would give eldest of each date.

```
select a.* from 
( select t.* , 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, product , revenue ORDER BY data DESC) 
 AS rn 
from your_table t
) a
where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'order by desc' on Data column to get the most recent one at the top and so on.